# Upgrading Memory for Lenovo 510 i7

Tags: memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade memory for my  Laptop Lenovo 510 i7.at the moment it has 6GB I would like add another 8GB.
Please let me know if it is possible
Thank you
Regards
Minu

Comment: You should check Lenovo's website. We need to know how many RAM slots your machine has and how many you are currently using. There is no way to answer unless you give us this information.

Comment: Head to a memory company's site like Kingston.com or Crucial.com, they both have utilities that allow you to pick a make/model and they'll tell you what RAM and capacities your device can handle. Here's the [results for your ThinkPad](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/Default.aspx?DeviceType=3&Mfr=LEN&Line=ThinkPad&Model=59219&Description=Kingston_System_Specific_Memory_for_Lenovo_ThinkPad_T510).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can add another 8GB on top of the 6 you already have.

Per Lenovo you can either have 6GB of memory running at 10677mhz or you can have 8GB running at 1333mhz (2 - 4GB DIMs)

Here is some more information on your model

http://www.lenovo.com/us/en/PDFs/ThinkPad_T410_T510_Datasheet.html